# How to export youtube favorites as a list of URL's?

Tags: api, youtube

How would you go about exporting youtube favorites and, if possible, importing too?

Is there an API we can interact with, as developers? If not, can you think a workaround?

I would prefer doing this in PHP, but any other language is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an API available.  I've not checked, but assume a user's favourites can be accessed like any other playlist.  The documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference

There's a package in the Zend framwork for interacting with all Google services, which has several YouTube specific modules.  It's talked about in the above documentation.  Personally, I feel it's a bit too heavy for many tasks, but do use it when I need to get something up and running quickly.